# Google Signin with expo-auth-session on standalone Android app, browser closes but nothing happens

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Signin using expo-auth-session and following the [guide here](https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#google). Everything works fine in Expo Client in my GenyMotion emulator. I made the configuration for Android standalone app and built an apk to test on an actual device. On my phone, after I press the Sign In button, a browser is launched and let me pick the Google account I want to use. But after that, the browser closes, returns to the app and nothing else happen. A fix would be warmly welcomed.
Here is the second example code I wrote to test with a fresh new project:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {

    const [gUser, setGUser] = useState(null);
    const [reqError, setReqError] = useState('');

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        expoClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        androidClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        // iosClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        // webClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
            const { authentication } = response;

            getGoogleUser(authentication.accessToken)
        }
    }, [response]);

    const getGoogleUser = async (accessToken) => {
        try{
            let gUserReq = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo',
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                    }
                }
            );
            
            console.log(gUserReq.data);
            setGUser(gUserReq.data);
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log('GoogleUserReq error: ', error);
            setReqError(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                reqError !== '' &&
                <View>
                    <Text>There was an error</Text>
                    <Text>{JSON.stringify(reqError, 'reqEr', 4)}</Text>
                </View>
            }

            <Text style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }}>Signed user</Text>

            {
                gUser === null && 
                <Text>No user</Text>
            }

            {
                gUser !== null && 
                <Text>{JSON.stringify(gUser, null, 4)}</Text>
            }

            <Button
                disabled={!request}
                title="Sign in"
                onPress={() => promptAsync()}               
            />

            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}
```

And here comes the expo diagnostics output:

```
Expo CLI 3.27.13 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)
      Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.19.0 - /usr/bin/node
      npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^38.0.0 => 38.0.10 
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz => 0.62.2 
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 3.27.13
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, it seems that after the expo response, the response from the hook doesn't change, and doesn't trigger the useEffect.. but I'm unsure about what is happening here or how could I fix it

Comment: Did you find a fix finally ? @GabrielRohden 's patch is working ?

Answer (score 1):

So, looks like this is a bug with the `expo-auth-session` package, I'm not sure why, but [this condition](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/95a84b594ffb2afdb5e9b06da916a50953efe897/packages/expo-auth-session/src/providers/Google.ts#L358-L360) here may cause this issue:

```js
setFullResult(fullResult ?? result);
```

changing it to:

```
setFullResult(result);
```

Seems to fix it for me. You can use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) if that fix works for you

I've also opened an issue about this because I believe that this is a bug
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11714

Edit:

you also need to add the result as a dependency of the effect that contains the `setFullResult`

Comment: Thanks, for me your patch fixes the first problem but results in `{"type":"dismiss"}` as a response.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using expo-auth-session. Referring to [AuthSession](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#usage-in-standalone-apps) documentation, the scheme should be the same as android.package in app.json, as mentioned [here](https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#android-native): "Your app needs to conform to the URI scheme matching your android.package (ex. com.myname.mycoolapp:/)". Now everything's work fine after changing it.

Comment: I dont think that this is the same problem because when the scheme is wrong you dont get any redirect, you also get a "uri doesnt match" error from google.